# Como desabilitar campo com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Possuo esses campos HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.HabilitaTeclado" type="checkbox" id="cbHabilitarTeclado" onclick="HTeclado();" />
    <label class="control-label">Biometria</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.SentidoTeclado" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.SentidoTeclado" id="cbSentidoTeclado" class="form-control">
        <option value="I">Irrelevante</option>
        <option value="E">Entrada</option>
        <option value="S">Saída</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Estou utilizando esta função para poder bloquear o campo, porém ela não funciona:

```
function HTeclado() { 
    document.getElementById('cbSentidoTeclado').disabled = false;

    if ($("#cbHabilitarTeclado").prop('checked') == true) {
        $("#cbSentidoTeclado").prop("disabled", true); 
    }
    else { 
        $("#cbSentidoTeclado").prop("disabled", false);
    }
}
```

Dessa forma não está funcionando, como posso resolver? Obrigado.

Comment: Está misturando **Vanilla** com **jQuery** pq?

Comment: Ja tentei de vérias formas, ai cheguei nesta, nenhuma dá certo, é que fui tentando várias vezes de modo diferente.

Comment: Vc que desabilitar o select clicando no checkbox é isto?

Comment: Se ele for true habilita, se for false desabilita.

Comment: Coloque aspas no valor do disabled

Comment: @GabrielFernandes não entendi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solução utilizando jquery:

Primeiro certifique-se de que adicionou a biblioteca jquery no head e em seguida insira o código javascript/jquery, exemplo:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#cbHabilitarTeclado").on("click", function(){
            if($(this).prop("checked")){
              $("#cbSentidoTeclado").prop("disabled", true); 
          }
          else{
              $("#cbSentidoTeclado").prop("disabled", false);
          }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

Seu html no body ficaria assim:

```
<body>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.HabilitaTeclado" type="checkbox" id="cbHabilitarTeclado" />
        <label class="control-label">Biometria</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.SentidoTeclado" class="control-label"></label>
        <select asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.SentidoTeclado" id="cbSentidoTeclado" class="form-control">
            <option value="I">Irrelevante</option>
            <option value="E">Entrada</option>
            <option value="S">Saída</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado, era isto mesmo que eu precisava.

Answer (score 7):

Uma forma mais enxuta apenas usando o próprio estado do `checkbox`: se ele for `true` (checado), o elemento é desabilitado; se for `false` (não checado), o elemento é habilitado. Um `if` neste caso é dispensável:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#cbHabilitarTeclado").on("click", function(){
      $("#cbSentidoTeclado")
      .prop("disabled", this.checked); 
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.HabilitaTeclado" type="checkbox" id="cbHabilitarTeclado" />
  <label class="control-label">Biometria</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <label asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.SentidoTeclado" class="control-label"></label>
  <select asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.SentidoTeclado" id="cbSentidoTeclado" class="form-control">
      <option value="I">Irrelevante</option>
      <option value="E">Entrada</option>
      <option value="S">Saída</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Acho que vc deve ter se perdido quando tentou misturar como eu disse Vanilla com jQuery.

```js
function HTeclado() { 

    if ($("#cbHabilitarTeclado").prop('checked') == true) {
        $("#cbSentidoTeclado").prop("disabled", false); 
    }
    else { 
        $("#cbSentidoTeclado").prop("disabled", true);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-6">
    <input asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.HabilitaTeclado" type="checkbox" id="cbHabilitarTeclado" onclick="HTeclado();" />
    <label class="control-label">Biometria</label>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <label asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.SentidoTeclado" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="ConfiguracaoTecnibra.SentidoTeclado" id="cbSentidoTeclado" class="form-control" disabled>
        <option value="I">Irrelevante</option>
        <option value="E">Entrada</option>
        <option value="S">Saída</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function HTeclado() { 
    document.getElementById('cbSentidoTeclado').disabled = false;

    if ($("#cbHabilitarTeclado").prop('checked') == true) {
        $("#cbSentidoTeclado option").prop("disabled", "true"); 
    }
    else { 
        $("#cbSentidoTeclado option").prop("disabled", "true");
    }
}
```

Funcionou quando eu coloquei aspas no 'true' e 'false'.
Sem as aspas não funcionava, vê se é isso.

Comment: Não funciona desta forma.